# How can I verify the date entered into DatePicker?

Tags: java, date, datepicker, javafx-8

I have problem with the code below:

```
public DatePicker data = new DatePicker();
String date = "2014-08-15";

public void verify() {
if (data.getValue().equals(date)) { 
System.out.println("Success!!!");
}

}
```

If date selected in the `DatePicker` (by mouse-click) is equal to the date of the `String` "date" variable, than I want that message to appear (actualy I want some coordinates to change but for you to understand I put a message).

Comment: what type of object is `date`?

Comment: I believe ScaryWombat meant to ask: what type of object is the return value of `getValue()`? (`date` is a String) Did you mean `DatePicker` to be a JavaFX [DatePicker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html) object whose `getValue` returns a [`java.time.LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer by nejinx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25173305/642706) is correct.

If you meant "DatePicker" to be the [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) [`DatePicker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html) class that returns a [java.time.LocalDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) object, then you need to make your comparison with another java.time.LocalDate object.

```
java.time.LocalDate targetLocalDate = LocalDate.of( 2014, 8, 15 );
// OR… LocalDate target = LocalDate.parse( "2014-08-15" );
LocalDate localDatePicked = datePicker.getValue();
if ( localDatePicked.equals( targetLocalDate ) 
{
    System.out.println("Success!!!");
}
```

Comment: `java.local.` seems unnecessary?

Comment: @ıɯɐƃoʇǝızuǝʞ Thanks for correction. (a) java.local was a mistake, meant to be java.time. (b) I included one qualified name to be clear on the package in use, as it is so new. And [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) happens to have the same class name.

Answer (score 1):

data.getValue().equals() only compares LocalDate objects and returns false for all other comparisons:

Checks if this date is equal to another date. 
Compares this LocalDate with another ensuring that the date is the same.

Only objects of type LocalDate are compared, other types return false.

REF:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#equals-java.lang.Object-

If you want to compare your data DatePicker with date string you would need to perform a string compare or create a LocalDate object to compare with the DatePicker's LocalDate object returned by data.getValue()

Comment: Why the downvote, with no comment? This answer appears to me to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

From the [DatePicker docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html) getValue() returns a `LocalDate`.
And you can create a proper `LocalDate` for comparison with the `LocalDate.of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)` ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-int-int-)) method. Your specified date can be created with this code:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2014, 8, 15);
```

And compared with the exact same code:

```
public void verify() {
    if (data.getValue().equals(date)) { 
        System.out.println("Success!!!");
    }
}
```

Also, the `equals` method of `LocalDate` only works on other `LocalDate`s.

Comment: Your statement about [`LocalDate.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) output varying from computer to computer is incorrect. Doc says: `The output will be in the ISO-8601 format uuuu-MM-dd.`